# Why do my three-way switches only work in one configuration?

Tags: wiring

I replaced a switch with a 3 way dimmer. There are 3 switches plus the dimmer to control 1 light. The only way the switches work is if the dimmer is in the on position then I can put the light on and off with the other switches. Why is that?

Comment: Short answer: because you wired it up wrong. Show us some pics and/or diagrams of what you've done and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Was it a 3-way circuit before? Which wires were the messengers?

Comment: Can you post pictures of the insides of the boxes in question?

Comment: Voting to close. Not enough information and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

You wired it wrong, or the switch you added is defective.

If you want more detail than that, update your question with a complete and accurate discription of the circuit, photographs of the wiring you changed, and details (model number) of the dimmer you installed.